# How to: Pass Arguments to Python Script via Powershell

Tags: python, powershell

I am attempting to pass 2 arguments to a python script via Powershell.

CODE:

```
$env:PATHEXT += ";.py"

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;c:\Program Files\lcpython15\", "User") 

$args1 = "Test1"
$args2 = "Test2"
$Python_SetAttrib = "c:\ProgramData\set_cust_attr.py "

python $Python_SetAttrib $args1 $args2

USAGE FROM CMD.exe: 
c:\ProgramData\set_cust_attr.py <custom attribute name> <custom attribute value>
```

ERROR:

```
PS C:\ProgramData> python $Python_SetAttrib + $args1 +  $args2
usage: c:\ProgramData\set_cust_attr.sh <custom attribute name> <custom attribute value>
OR
usage: c:\ProgramData\Opsware\set_cust_attr.sh --valuefile <path to file with value     in     it> <custom attribute name>

python.exe : Got more than one custom attribute name.
At line:1 char:7
+ python <<<<  $Python_SetAttrib + $args1 +  $args2
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Got more than one custom attribute     name.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Unhandled exception in thread started by 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\client\__init__.py", line 88, in pumpthread
  File "C:\Program Files\lcpython15\lib\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 3, in ?
    pywintypes.__import_pywin32_system_module__("pythoncom", globals())
  File "C:\Program Files\lcpython15\Lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line     68, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    import _win32sysloader
ImportError: No module named _win32sysloader
```

Comment: Judging from the error message, the issue seems to be with your Python code, not with your PowerShell code.

Comment: Why are you using the `+` operator between the parameters (`python $Python_SetAttrib + $args1 +  $args2`)? Do you want to concatenate the arguments (if so, you'd need to surround them with parens, `($Python_SetAttrib + $args1 + $args2)`)? If not, I don't know what you mean. If you mean for them to be separate parameters to the python script, then you wouldn't need `+` at all.

Comment: When I pass the parameters via ( ) it gives me : " Unexpected token 'args1' in expression or statement."

Comment: Currently there is a .bat to run python and the script. So, it would works if I run (at cmd line) : attrib.bat <arg1> <arg2>

The .bat just contains : : python.exe <python script.py> 

I'm trying to not use the .bat file by calling:
python.exe <python script> <arg1> <arg2>

Comment: For clarity: `python c:\ProgramData\set_cust_attr.py + $args1 + $args2` calls `set_cust_attr.py` with 4 arguments: `+`, `$args1`, `+` and `$args2`.

Comment: just 2 arguments. But I've found that this works: python c:\ProgramData\set_cust_attr.py <Argument1> <Argument2> However when I try to substite out the .py script and Arguments for variables, it fails. Something like this: python $pythonscript $arg1 $arg2

I think I added the '+' while throwing ideas at it to make it work. :)

Comment: Got it!
    $env:Path += ";c:\Program Files\lcpython15";
    $env:PATHEXT += ";.py";
    $arg1 = "Test3"
    $arg2 = "Testing"
    $arg3 = 'c:\ProgramData\set_cust_attr.py'
    python $arg3 $arg1 $arg2

Answer (score 1):

Got it! Darn single quotes.....

```
$env:Path += ";c:\Program Files\lcpython15";
$env:PATHEXT += ";.py"; 
$arg1 = "Test3" 
$arg2 = "Testing" 
$arg3 = 'c:\ProgramData\set_cust_attr.py' 
python $arg3 $arg1 $arg2
```